# Lacunar series with an interesting (in-formula) symmetry.

Tags: cv.complex-variables

So, I wrote out a table of functions like so:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}q^{n}=$ $+q^{1}$  $-q^{2}$ $+q^{3}$ $-q^{4}$ $+q^{5}$ + $\ldots$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}q^{n^{2}}=$ $-q^{1}$ $+q^{4}$ $-q^{9}$ & $+q^{16}$ $-q^{25}$ $\ldots$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}q^{n^{3}}=$ $+q^{1}$ $-q^{8}$  $+q^{27}$  $-q^{64}$ $+q^{125}$ $\ldots$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}q^{n^{4}}=$  $-q^{1}$ & $+q^{16}$  $-q^{81}$  $+q^{256}$ $-q^{625}$ $\ldots$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}q^{n^{5}}=$  $+q^{1}$  $-q^{32}$  $+q^{243}$  $-q^{1024}$ $+q^{3125}$  $\ldots$

And noticed that it is possible to rewrite (by transposing the first column so 
it becomes the first row). The essential (though incomplete) statement of the
symmetry here is:

$X(q) = \sum_{m}^{\infty} \sum_{n}^{\infty} (-1)^{m+n} q^{m^{n}} = \sum_{m}^{\infty} \sum_{n}^{\infty} (-1)^{m+n} q^{n^{m}}$

Writing it out appropriately:

$X(q)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m}q^{2^{m}} + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m+1}q^{3^{m}} + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m}q^{4^{m}} + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m+1}q^{5^{m}} + \ldots$

$X(q) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}q^{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}q^{n^{2}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}q^{n^{3}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}q^{n^{4}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}q^{n^{5}} + \ldots$

Using [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) I get numerically:

```
>>> nsum(lambda p: (nsum(lambda n: ((-1)**(n+1))*((1/2.0)**(n**(2.0*p-1))), [1,inf])), [1,inf]) + nsum(lambda p: (nsum(lambda n: ((-1)**(n))*((1/2.0)**(n**(2.0*p))), [1,inf])), [1,inf])
mpf('-0.10999554665856692')
>>> nsum(lambda p: (nsum(lambda n: ((-1)**n)*((1/2.0)**((2.0*p)**n)), [0,inf])), [1,inf]) + nsum(lambda p: (nsum(lambda n: ((-1)**(n+1))*((1/2.0)**((2.0*p+1)**n)), [0,inf])), [1,inf])
mpf('-0.10999554665855271')
```

And using mpmath's plotting facility, I obtained a picture of $X(q)$:

[image]

Questions:

1. $\lim_{q\rightarrow 0} X(q) = -1/2$ by numerical evaluation, but just algebraically evaluating the function definition would lead one to believe that X(0)=0. What's going on here?
2. All theta function identities (including Ramanujan's mock theta functions) that I've seen involve terms with $q^{n^2}$, but nothing higher in the uppermost exponent. Is there any work on series with $q^{n^{3}}$ I've found [a paper by A. Sebbar](http://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/handle/2433/62866) which might be relevant.
3. Has the function $X(q)$ been studied before? And if so, under what name? Does it have any interesting properties which aren't obvious from its definition. What are the appropriate lower bounds for the most compact representation? (summation) Does this function have any interesting symmetries under the modular group?

Comment: The sum defining X(q) is not convergent.  I see the documentation of `nsum` mentions that it will happily sum certain divergent series, but if you don't know exactly what it is doing, this means it is silently producing nonsense.

Comment: Reid: when you say it is not convergent, are you claiming it fails to converge for each q in the unit disc? or merely that it fails to converge for some q in the (closed) unit disc?

Comment: @Yemon: It converges only when q=0; consider the terms when m=0.  Abel or Cesaro means will converge, and I'm guessing that that is where the 1/2 comes from, but Reid's assessment seems fair.

Comment: Right, it certainly might be the case that you get an interesting function by regularizing the sum $q-q+q-q+\cdots$ appropriately, but without knowing what `nsum` is doing, question 1 is hard to answer.

Comment: Jonas, Reid: yes, of course, I was being dim (and failing to read the relevant expression properly). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: A somewhat related question appears in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, Exercise 6.63(c).

Comment: Get rid of the first term of the series, and I  think that mess sums absolutely in the interior of the unit disk. :) The limit as $q\rightarrow 0$ is uninterestingly $0$.  

In fact then the whole story is the alternating sum of $\pm q$.
Depending on your method, that could add up to a lot of things.

One of my favorite chapters of any book is the first chapter of Hardy's "Divergent Series".  At the end of it, you are pretty sure that Hardy had lost his marbles.